# Need Qt Creator Source files

Tags: c++, qt4, qt-creator

I want to create a similar GUI as Qt Creator main layout and thus I am looking for Qt Creator Source files.

Can anyone direct me from where to download.

Answer (score 10):

Have a look at the gitorious repo: http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-creator